# Coded ui test in a multithreaded scenario and control not found.

Tags: coded-ui-tests

As you all know Coded ui playback can be kind of slow depending on the controls you're querying.

To try and solve this issue I am looking at adding some multithreading capabilities to the test.

Here is a for loop which works successfully, now converted to a Parallel.For - only the control cannot be found (not at all).

```
Parallel.For(0, totalItems, (i, loopState) =>
                {
                    DxLookup.OpenPopup();
                    var cell = _popupGrid.GetCell(viewName, column.ColumnName, i);
                    cell.DrawHighlight();

                    if (cell.ValueAsString == item)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        loopState.Stop();

                    }

                });
```

The code fails on the DxLookup.OpenPopup - because the control is not found. Looks like it could be thread related.

How is it possible to access a test control from another thread then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about Coded UI playback supports multi-threading capabilities check this link for playback related information
[Configure Playback](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/08/10/configuring-playback-in-vstt-2010.aspx)

you may try come other techniques to speedup the playback

Answer (score 0):

what kind of app are you trying to test? if it's a winforms app multithrreading is problematic.
try testing wheter you can locate tha main app window or any kind of control. if not you'll know it's a threading problem. if you can locate any kind of control just not the desired control you'll be able to tweak the search configurations to loacte the control.
hope this helps